# Changing the position of element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is supposed to change the position of a paragraph (with the id 'Text') more to the right each time it is looped. It doesn't work though and I can't figure out how to fix it, so I would be very happy if someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

```
  var x = 0;

  d.style.position = "absolute";

  function myLoop () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      x += 10;
      document.getElementById('Text').style.left = x+'px';
      myLoop();
    }, 100)
  }
```

(This is everything in the script)

Comment: so, `d` is the cached value for `document.getElementById('Text')` ? Why are you not reusing `d` then? If that's really all of your script, `d` is undefined and this line breaks the execution by throwing an error. What does your console say?

Comment: Where are you calling the `myLoop()` function initially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

1) You have never defined d. That causing to stop the script right there without executing next lines of code.

2) You have never called `myLoop()` function.

So with all corrections.

```js
var x = 0;
var d = document.getElementById('Text');
d.style.position = "absolute";
myLoop();
  function myLoop () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      x += 10;
      d.style.left = x+'px';
      myLoop();
    }, 100)
  }
```

```html
<div id="Text">Test </div>
```

Besides this solution, you might have a to take a look at setInterval function which reduce your code a bit.

```js
var x = 0;
var d = document.getElementById('Text');
d.style.position = "absolute";
myLoop();
  function myLoop () {
    setInterval(function () {
      x += 10;
      d.style.left = x+'px';
    }, 100)
  }
```

```html
<div id="Text">Test </div>
```

Comment: You should have defined `d`, so it would be cached and make a substantial performance improvement.

Comment: @JeremyThille Absolutely true.

Comment: Nice alternative using `setInterval`, but now the `myLoop()` function is useless :)

Comment: @JeremyThille No. No. OP might want to call `myLoop()` on a button click ?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

`d` have not any value so define `d` with

`d = document.getElementById('Text');`

and call your function `myLoop` so its work

```js
var x = 0;
d = document.getElementById('Text');
d.style.position = "absolute";
myLoop();

function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    x += 10;
    d.style.left = x + 'px';
    myLoop();
  }, 100)
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='Text'>
```

Comment: Reuse `d` inside the loop (performance improvement) and I'll upvote

Comment: I said it, I did it.